# Falló la conexión al servidor en «localhost» (::1), puerto 5432: FATAL para pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql

He instalado postgresql-server la version 14.7 en OpenSuse Leap 15.4, cuando abro PgAdmin 4, noto que no aparece en la lista de **servers**, como en windows, y al añadir el servidor  me manda este error

> falló la conexión al servidor en «localhost» (::1), puerto 5432: FATAL: la autentificación Ident falló para el usuario «postgres»

Ya he revisado algunas configuraciones pero nada me ha funcionado, y es lo mismo si creo un usuario e intento acceder con el. Alguien que tenga alguna noción de lo que pasa.
Como siempre agradezco los comentarios de los posibles problemas y una probable solución o la solución.

Os dejo aquí algo de información de lo que tengo:

**systemctl status posgresql**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pg_hba.conf**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Significa que hay que cambiar el método de autenticación, de ident a otra cosa. Revisaste la documentación?

Comment: @Alfabravo No, no la he revisado, ¿podrías decirme como?, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te menciona @alfabravo, debes cambiar el mecanismo de autenticación,   puedes añadir la autenticación por `md5`(si te sabes el password) en vez de `ident`, si no te sabes el password usa `trust`, esta no te va a pedir password, siempre luego del cambio debes hacer un reload del servicio

La documentación esta aqui: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Muchas gracias!! @Anthony